# input element won't break to new line; stays on same line with another input

Tags: html, css

So this is the HTML mark-up I have for my page:

```
<div id="portal-central">
        <div id="portal-central-login">
          <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <input id="login_username" name="username" type="text" value="firstname_lastname" onBlur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'firstname_lastname'" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Firstname_Lastname') this.value = ''" required />
            <input id="login_password" name="password" type="password" value="Password" onBlur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'password'" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Password') this.value = ''" required />

            <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#portal-central {
  height: 192px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 10px solid #65825f;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #65825f;
}

#portal-central-login {
    height: 152px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

#portal-central-login form {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
}

#portal-central-login input {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #b5b5b5;
}

#portal-central-login input[type=text] {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#portal-central-login input[type=password]{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#portal-central-login input[type=submit]{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

For some reason, the submit input is sticking to the side of the password text field and it's starting to wind me up a bit. I've been racking my brain trying to figure out what's wrong but I am stumped so I'm looking for some guidance.

As seen here:

[image: As seen here.]

Comment: can you clarify what browser you see that behaviour in.  When I pasted your example into a JSFiddle it seemed to work just fine.  That said, by default the inputs are display: inline-block, and as such they will all flow onto one line if the width permits.

Comment: @NickSharp Google Chrome, buddy. And yeah - but using inline-block was the only way I could get the form to center properly in the portal-central div.

Comment: Alternatively, you could most likely get what you wanted by just using a <br/> in between... Telling it to "break" the inline elements where you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` elements are by default [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente). This means they will share the same line, unless acted upon by another condition.

Just change the `input`s to [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), and each will have their own line.

Add this to your CSS:

```
input { display: block; }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yt6joz9j/

---

UPDATE (based on comments)

To keep the form centered, just use a flexbox. Remove the code above and make this adjustment:

```
#portal-central-login form {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yt6joz9j/1/

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought, however - it throws off the centering of the form. Before: http://i.imgur.com/3ZUlbsN.png After: http://i.imgur.com/ryPt5BA.png

Comment: Added alternative solution. Centers form on the page.

Comment: Your question focuses on the `input` being on a new line. You don't mention anything about centering, so I'm not totally clear on what the goal is. If I'm missing something let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in that respect; your updated solution worked great - thanks a lot fella.